# StaggeredGridLayoutManager for creating view like this

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

[image]

I want to create a view like the image,can  i use StaggerredGridLayoutManager for this kind of view if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

No. StaggeredGridLayoutManager doesn't support items that differ in both width and height. You would need to use an external library, this one might help you out: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Fair warning: I've used this library and it hasn't been supported for a long time, and it definitely has some bugs in it. So read up on the Git issues first.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved using `SpannableGridLayoutManager` for more detail answer follow the link provided [Solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821961/how-to-design-spannable-gridview-using-recyclerview-spannablegridlayoutmanager/48825958#48825958) .

This solution is working perfectly.